# Large (20m) data viewer with filter for int, float and date

Tags: database

I have 20m rows x 10 columns data looks like:

```
     Col1  Col2  Col3    Col4 ... Col10
Row1 [str] [int] [float] ...
Row2 ...
...
Row20,000,000 ...
```

I am looking for a data viewer which supports:

1. Filtering for int, float and date. E.g.: 1.5 < v1 < 2.3, v2 > 0, date from 2019-02-15 to 2021-08-31.
2. Filtering with GUI helper instead of text like SQL query language.
3. Handling data as large as 20m rows x 10 columns.
4. Even better if can export selected partial data to JSON/CSV/MS Excel/any other formats that can be handled by code.

Actually SQL query language meets all the requirements, just that this viewer will be used by end-users without technical background, hence it's better to have a GUI filter helper.

I can convert the data to any format that the data viewer requires. It is not troubling to write one but I guess there may be one present.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If on Linux, consider using [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) - which might work on Windows or MacOSX. Contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` and give more details

Answer (score 1):

Sqlitebrowser and [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io) fits all requirements. Thanks algorithm for suggesting related questions.